# EC2 t2.micro unexpected charging in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-billing

I'm having a hard time understanding why I am being charged on a EC2 instance I'm not running.
I'm using a IAM account, I have an RDS t3.medium up on the master account where the RDS cost is charged, but it appears I'm being charged as my IAM account for a EC2 I dont' use.

[image: MY AWS BILLING]

[image: IAM USER EC2 CONSOLE]

So what may be causing this ec2 charging?

Comment: Is your screen captured on the US EAST region?

Comment: @Lamanus Yes. In the first screen is on "global" and the second is on "US East (Ohio)" as it is written under "Resources".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being charged for a t2.micro Amazon EC2 instance in the Ohio region because such an instance is/was running.

If you are still in the first 12 months of your AWS Account, **there will be no charge for this instance** because the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) includes 750 hours per month of a t2.micro instance.

You should look in the EC2 management console for Ohio, just to check whether the instance is still running.